# automation of title in a python function

Tags: python-3.x, automation

I have a made a function in python to plot my data. this function takes data from file1 and every time I select different name (2nd argument of function) to be plotted. 
this function has 2 problems:
1- `set_title('MYC')` ---> in which I asked the function to set the title of plot
2- `plt.savefig('MYC.pdf')` ---> to save the plot with the same name as title.

if I want to run this function for the name "`MYC`" I have to manually type it in 2 mentioned items. but I want to make automatic and they should be the same as name (which is the 2nd argument in the function). here is the function and how to run it for `file.txt` and "`MYC`".

```
def test(file1, name):
    df = pd.read_csv(file1, sep = '\t')
    p = sns.violinplot(data=df,
                   x = 'group',
                   y = 'Value',
                   notch=True).set_title('MYC')
    plt.xticks(rotation=45)
    l = plt.xlabel('')
    plt.ylabel('normal')
    plt.savefig('MYC.pdf')


test("file.txt", "MYC")
```

do you know how to change the function to get the plot with title and file name similar to the 2nd argument of this function?

Answer (score 1):

You are passing `"MYC"` as a string which is assigned to name in the same way `"file.txt"` is assigned to `file1`. So just refer to it using `name`

This should do what you need:

```
def test(file1, name):
    df = pd.read_csv(file1, sep = '\t')
    p = sns.violinplot(data=df,
                   x = 'group',
                   y = 'Value',
                   notch=True).set_title(name)
    plt.xticks(rotation=45)
    l = plt.xlabel('')
    plt.ylabel('normal')
    plt.savefig(f'{name}.pdf')


test("file.txt", "MYC")
```

Comment: Your answer is good - I edited it however to use the new f-string formatting, as there are no reasons to use the old `.format()` method in this case.

Comment: Well, apart from the fact the question is `python 3.x` and not `python 3.6 +`

Comment: Pyton 3.6 is 3 years old now. Or one is stuck in Python 2.7. A few others are stuck in 3.5 coding backend code for Python in old servers. Everyone else can be assumed to be running a Python with less than 2 years old. One answer does not _have_ to be compatible with all possible Python versions, but you can improve your answer with that "except" clause if your prefer.